# RabbitMQ queue length limit not honored

Tags: rabbitmq

I have tried using both the `max-length` and `x-max-length` arguments to limit queue lengths to no avail. I can't tell if I'm incorrectly using the arguments, whether it's due a limitation of using the RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin, or if there's an actual bug in RabbitMQ.

---

There's an exchange for use by the [RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange) which has multiple queues attached to it (these queues are only used through this exchange). A message is sent to one of these queues.

Whenever I redeploy the application server, there are two instances running for a brief period of time (rolling updates). Since both applications are publishing messages to the queues, each queue now has two messages in it. Every time there's a redeploy of the application server, yet another duplicate message is enqueued even though the `max-length` and/or `x-max-length` arguments are set to `1`. I've even tried setting them to `0` but it didn't make any difference.

---

Here's how I'm declaring the queue:

[image: x-max-length]

Here's the policy I've applied to the queues:

[image: max-length]

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Message Deduplication Plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/issues). Seems like it could address your rolling-update use-case.

Comment: Yes, I was going to use that to solve for rolling updates. However, the loop use case I've mentioned cannot be solved by it since it's effectively acting as a cron job. I've since stopped using the RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin in favor of just asynchronously sleeping ten seconds instead.